# Projection of boundig box from lidar frame to camera image

Tags: ros2, simulation, camera, sensor-fusion, gazebo-ignition

i am trying to project the bounding box in 3d from lidar frame to camera image in 2d. I am doing this work in ignition-gazebo simulation. so, basically there is no real hardware except my pc. there is no rotation between the frames and translation is just 0.02 meter in z direction. I have written a code to project it on image. Although the bounding box is projecting at different location in the image. i am not sure what is wrong with my code. Can anyone please have a look into this? i have been stuck here for almost 2 months. Any suggestion is highly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from tf2_ros import TransformException
from tf2_ros.buffer import Buffer
from tf2_ros.transform_listener import TransformListener

import tf2_geometry_msgs
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo
from vision_msgs.msg import Detection3DArray, BoundingBox3D
import message_filters
from image_geometry import PinholeCameraModel

import numpy as np
import ros2_numpy as rnp
import cv2
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError


class Projection(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("projection")

        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.model = PinholeCameraModel()

        self.tf_buffer = Buffer()
        self.tf_listener = TransformListener(self.tf_buffer, self)

        self.camera_info_sub = self.create_subscription(
            CameraInfo, "camera_info", self.info_callback, 10)
        self.need_info = True

        self.camera_mat = None
        self.dist_coeffs = None
        
        # self.transformation_mat = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
        #                                     [0, 1, 0, 0],
        #                                     [0, 0 ,1.0, 0.02],
        #                                     [0, 0, 0, 1]] )
        

        # self.rvec, self.tvec = self.rot_trans(self.transformation_mat)

        # print(f"self.tvec:{self.tvec} ")
        # print(f"self.rvec:{self.rvec} ")

        self.lidar_detection_sub = message_filters.Subscriber(
            self, Detection3DArray, "cloud_detections")
        self.image_sub = message_filters.Subscriber(self, Image, "camera")

        self.camera_pub = self.create_publisher(Image, "bbbox_projection", 10)

        self.proj = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer(
            [self.image_sub, self.lidar_detection_sub], 10, 0.1)
        self.proj.registerCallback(self.posecallback)

        self.get_logger().info("Projecting bounding box on image.....")

    def info_callback(self, info_msg):
        self.camera_mat = np.array(info_msg.k).reshape(3, 3)
        self.dist_coeffs = np.array(info_msg.d)
        if self.need_info:
            self.get_logger().info(f'Inside info callback')
            self.model.fromCameraInfo(info_msg)
            self.need_info = False

    def posecallback(self, img_msg, detection_msg):
        self.get_logger().info("callback initiated.....", once=True)
        try:
            img = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(img_msg, "bgr8")
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            self.get_logger().error(e)

        if self.camera_mat is not None:
            for detection in detection_msg.detections:
                # cx, cy, cz = rnp.numpify(detection.bbox.center.position)
                pose_msg = (detection.bbox.center)
                print(f"original_pose_msg:{pose_msg} ")
                length, width,height = rnp.numpify(detection.bbox.size)

                transformed_pose = self.get_my_transform(
                    pose_msg, from_frame="lidar/lidar_link/gpu_lidar", to_frame="camera/link/camera")

                corner_points = self.calculate_bounding_box_corners(
                    transformed_pose.pose, length=length, width=width, height=height)


                image_points_ = self.get_3d_image_points(corner_points)
                print(f"image_points_:{image_points_} ")

                # bbox_image_ = self.draw_3d_bounding_box(img, image_points_.astype(int))
                x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = self.get_bbox_coordinates(
                    image_points_)
                bbox_image_ = self.draw_box(img, (int(x_min), int(
                    y_min)), (int(x_max), int(y_max)), (0, 0, 255))

                bbox_msg = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(bbox_image_)
                bbox_msg.header.frame_id = img_msg.header.frame_id

                self.camera_pub.publish(bbox_msg)

    def get_my_transform(self, input_pose, from_frame, to_frame):
        pose_stamped = tf2_geometry_msgs.PoseStamped()
        pose_stamped.pose = input_pose
        pose_stamped.header.frame_id = from_frame
        pose_stamped.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()

        try:
            output_pose_stamped = self.tf_buffer.transform(
                pose_stamped, to_frame, rclpy.duration.Duration(seconds=1.0))
            return output_pose_stamped
        except TransformException as e:
            raise e

    def calculate_bounding_box_corners(self, pose, length, width, height):
        half_length = length/2.0
        half_width = width/2.0
        half_height = height/2.0
        position = pose.position
        orientation = pose.orientation

        rotation_mat = np.array([
            [1-2*(orientation.y**2+orientation.z**2), 2*(orientation.x*orientation.y - orientation.w *
                                                         orientation.z), 2*(orientation.x*orientation.z + orientation.w * orientation.y)],
            [2*(orientation.x * orientation.y + orientation.w*orientation.z), 1 - 2 * (orientation.x **
                                                                                       2 + orientation.z**2), 2 * (orientation.y * orientation.z - orientation.w * orientation.x)],
            [2*(orientation.x * orientation.z + orientation.w * orientation.y), 2 * (orientation.y *
                                                                                     orientation.z + orientation.w * orientation.x), 1-2*(orientation.x**2 + orientation.y**2)]
        ])

        corners_local = np.array([
            [-half_length, -half_width, -half_height],
            [half_length, -half_width, -half_height],
            [half_length, half_width, -half_height],
            [-half_length, half_width, -half_height],
            [-half_length, -half_width, half_height],
            [half_length, -half_width, half_height],
            [half_length, half_width, half_height],
            [-half_length, half_width, half_height],
        ], dtype=np.float32)

        corner_points = np.dot(corners_local, rotation_mat.T) + \
            np.array([position.x, position.y, position.z])

        return corner_points

    def get_3d_corner_points(self, x, y, z, size):
        "return the corner point of the bounding box from center and size of the detection box in lidar frame"
        half_h, half_w, half_l = size/2
        corner_points = []
        for i in [-1, 1]:
            for j in [-1, 1]:
                for k in [-1, 1]:
                    corner = (x + i * half_w, y + j*half_h, z + k * half_l)
                    corner_points.append(corner)
        return corner_points

    def get_3d_image_points(self, corner_points):
        "return the bonding box corner point in the image frame in 3d"
        image_points = []
        for corner_ in corner_points:
            u, v = self.model.project3dToPixel(
                (corner_[2], corner_[1],  corner_[0]))
            image_points.append((u, v))
            # image_point,_ = cv2.projectPoints(corner_[:] ,self.rvec, self.tvec, self.camera_mat, self.dist_coeffs)
            # temp_point = image_point.tolist()
            # image_points.append(temp_point[0][0])
            
        image_np = np.array(image_points, dtype=np.float32)
        return image_np

    def get_bbox_coordinates(self, image_points):
        "return the bounding box coordinates in 2d"
        x = []
        y = []
        for i in image_points:
            temp_x = i[0]
            temp_y = i[1]
            x.append(temp_x)
            y.append(temp_y)
        x_min = np.min(x)
        x_max = np.max(x)
        y_min = np.min(y)
        y_max = np.max(y)
        print(f"x_min:{x_min} ")
        print(f"y_min:{y_min} ")

        return x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max

    def draw_3d_bounding_box(self, image, points):
        color = (0, 0, 255)
        for i in range(4):

            next_point = (i+1) % 4
            cv2.line(image, tuple(points[i]), tuple(
                points[next_point]), color, 2)
            cv2.line(image, tuple(points[i+4]),
                     tuple(points[next_point+4]), color, 2)
            cv2.line(image, tuple(points[i]), tuple(points[i+4]), color, 2)

        return image

    def draw_box(self, cv_image, x_position, y_position, color):
        cv2.rectangle(cv_image, x_position, y_position, color, 5)
        return cv_image

    def rot_trans(self, projection_matrix):
        "return the rotational and translation vector"
        (rvec, jac) = cv2.Rodrigues(projection_matrix[:3, :3])
        tvec = projection_matrix[:3, 3]
        return rvec, tvec
```

I am using ros2 humble and ignition gazebo fortress on ubuntu 22.04.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions.